# MATLAB: Is it possible to use a file as an input on a function?

Tags: matlab

I used uigetfile to let the user choose a file. And I saved said file on the matlab path. The thing is, I do not know the name of the file, only the extension.
Imagine the file extension is '.something'. How will I use it as a input argument in a function?
Thanks!

Comment: why don't you pass it as a text and do text processing afterwards?

Comment: @freude Not sure how to do that...
But I remembered now that I have the name of the file saved in the matlab path, as another file named "name.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a specific directory is known, one can get the list of files with a proper extension by using:

```
a=dir('*.something')
```

This function returns an array of structures, each structure describes a single file (name, date etc.). From the structures it is easy to extract the file name by `a(num_of_file).name`